# Como puedo enviar Json de angular 4 y trabajarlos en laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, angularjs-2.0

En el Front angular lo envio asi

```
Register(register:RegisterUser){
    return this._http.post(this.url+"auth",
         JSON.stringify(
    {'name':register.name,
    'email':register.email,
    'password':register.password})
        ,{headers:this.headers})
    .map(res=>res.json());

}
```

y en laravel me llega es esto::

```
string(17) "lo q trae angular" NULL
```

Esta es el metodo en laravel

```
 public function userAuth(Request $request){

            var_dump('lo q trae angular',$request->input('email'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer lo sin JSON.stringfiy(), es decir:-

this.http.post(this.url, register, {headers: this.headers});